# Inverse scale of predicted data in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network

Im trying to use a NN model to predict with new data. However predicted data is not of the correct scale (values obtained 1e-10 when it should be 0.3 etc).

In my model ive used minmaxscaler on the x and y data. The model gave me an R2 value of 0.9 when using the test train split method, and and MSE of 0.01% using a pipeline method and also the cross val method. So i believe the model ive created is ok.

here is the model ive made.

```
data=pd.read_csv(r'''F:\DataforANNfromIESFebAugPowerValues.csv''')
data.dropna(axis=0,how='all')

x=data[['Dry-bulb_temperature_C','Wind_speed_m/s','Cloud_cover_oktas','External_relative_humidity_%','Starrag1250','StarragEcospeed2538','StarragS191','StarragLX051','DoosanCNC6700','MakinoG7','HermleC52MT','WFL_Millturn','Hofler1350','MoriNT4250','MoriNT5400','NMV8000','MoriNT6600','MoriNVL1350','HermleC42','CFV550','MoriDura635','DMGUltrasonic10']]
y=data[['Process_heat_output_waste_kW','Heating_plant_sensible_load_kW','Cooling_plant_sensible_load_kW','Relative_humidity_%','Air_temperature_C','Total_electricity_kW','Chillers_energy_kW','Boilers_energy_kW']]

epochs=150
learning_rate=0.001
decay_rate=learning_rate/epochs
optimiser=keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr=learning_rate, schedule_decay=decay_rate)

def create_model():
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(21, input_dim=22, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(19, activation='relu')) #hidden layer 2
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='sigmoid')) #output layer
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimiser,metrics=['accuracy','mse'])
    return model

scaler=MinMaxScaler()


x=MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(x)
print(x)
y=MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(y)
model=KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0,epochs=150, batch_size=70)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=150, batch_size=70)


##SET UP NEW DATA FOR PREDICTIONS

xnewdata=pd.read_csv(r'''F:\newdatapowervalues.csv''')
xnewdata.dropna(axis=0,how='all')
xnew=xnewdata[['Dry-bulb_temperature_C','Wind_speed_m/s','Cloud_cover_oktas','External_relative_humidity_%','Starrag1250','StarragEcospeed2538','StarragS191','StarragLX051','DoosanCNC6700','MakinoG7','HermleC52MT','WFL_Millturn','Hofler1350','MoriNT4250','MoriNT5400','NMV8000','MoriNT6600','MoriNVL1350','HermleC42','CFV550','MoriDura635','DMGUltrasonic10']]

xnew=MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(xnew)
ynew=model.predict(xnew)

ynewdata=pd.DataFrame(data=ynew)
ynewdata.to_csv(r'''F:\KerasIESPowerYPredict.csv''',header=['Process_heat_output_waste_kW','Heating_plant_sensible_load_kW','Cooling_plant_sensible_load_kW','Relative_humidity_%','Air_temperature_C','Total_electricity_kW','Chillers_energy_kW','Boilers_energy_kW'])
```

seeing ive used the scaler on the inital training model, i thought i would also need to do this to the new data. Ive tried doing 
    scaler.inverse_transform(ynew)
after model.predict(ynew) however i get the error that the minmaxscaler instance isnt fitted to y yet.
Therefore, i tried using the pipeline method.

```
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', MinMaxScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, epochs=150, batch_size=70, verbose=0)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
pipeline.fit(x,y)
```

for the inital training model instead of

```
x=MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(x)
y=MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(y)
model=KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0,epochs=150, batch_size=70)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=150, batch_size=70)
```

i then used 
    ynew=pipeline.predict(xnew)
however this gave me data consisting mainly of 1's!

any idea on how i can predict correctly on this new data? im unsure which data to scale and which not too, as i believe that using the pipeline.predict would include scaling for x and y. therefore do i need some sort of inverse pipeline scalar after making these predictions?
many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is one minor and one major problem with your approach.

1. Minor one: there's no need to scale your target variable, it does not affect your optimisation function.
2. Major one: you fit the scaler again on the data on which you want to run the prediction. By doing this, you skew completely the relations you have in the data and hence the predicted output is of a very different scale. Also, you define `scaler` and later not use it. Let's fix it.

(...)

```
scaler=MinMaxScaler()

x=scaler.fit_transform(x)
model=KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0,epochs=150, batch_size=70)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=150, batch_size=70)


##SET UP NEW DATA FOR PREDICTIONS

xnewdata=pd.read_csv(r'''F:\newdatapowervalues.csv''')
xnewdata.dropna(axis=0,how='all')
xnew=xnewdata[['Dry-bulb_temperature_C','Wind_speed_m/s','Cloud_cover_oktas','External_relative_humidity_%','Starrag1250','StarragEcospeed2538','StarragS191','StarragLX051','DoosanCNC6700','MakinoG7','HermleC52MT','WFL_Millturn','Hofler1350','MoriNT4250','MoriNT5400','NMV8000','MoriNT6600','MoriNVL1350','HermleC42','CFV550','MoriDura635','DMGUltrasonic10']]

xnew=scaler.transform(xnew)
ynew=model.predict(xnew)

ynewdata=pd.DataFrame(data=ynew)
```

As you can see, we used the `scaler` first to learn the proper normnalisation factor and then used it (`transform`) on the new data on which we run `predict`.

Comment: thanks for your help. When i run the model without scaling y data i get a terrible model with a decreasing accuray with epochs and increasing loss. do i not need to scale the y data so its in the range of the activation function? thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice you're using `sigmoid` there. Replace it with `linear`.

Comment: Its not right to say that scaling the targets is unnecessary, it does change the optimization problem, you can easily see this in bounding box regression with neural networks.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro How does it change the optimisation? Can you illustrate how it affects the optimisation problem from math or algorithm standpoint? Here's one explanation how it does not affect it: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re

Comment: @LukaszTracewski For a neural network it does change it, as you normalize the targets *and* put an appropriate activation at the output, so the ranges match, for example, normalizing targets to [0, 1] and putting a sigmoid activation at the output of the network. The answer you linked does not apply for complex non-linear models where you also make small architectural changes. Another reason is that if you do not scale, the network has to learn the scale, so normalizing and forcing the network to use a determined scale removes one learning problem. Its not just a linear transformation.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro The link concerns stochastic gradient decent that is used to solve the problem. It's math, network complexity has nothing to do with it. With sigmoid it would indeed not work, but linear is just fine. Where is the extra scaling that it would have to learn? Can you demonstrate your point with either a formula or algorithm? What I fail to see is how gradient decent convergence is affected by scale of the target variable (assuming output is linear).

Comment: @LukaszTracewski No, you are seeing it in the wrong way, a network with linear output activation and another with sigmoid output activation produce completely different loss surfaces, its much easier to learn if the output ranges match. Its an empirical result, see the Faster R-CNN paper for example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thanks for the paper. I get your point now. Actually I'd expect `linear` to have better convergence than `sigmoid` in this case, as it's the `ReLU` earlier that matter. Perhaps this is not the best place for academic discussion. As you rightfully said, much of it is empirical and depends on a particular case.

Comment: Hi sorry to revive this thread. I have a doubt, during training I am scaling my features and not scaling my targets, and during prediction I should `transform` my test set and shouldn't do `inverse_transform` on my predictions ?  Also the choice of scaling targets ultimately depends on activation of my output layer. Am i correct ?